# Separate frontmatter (metadata) in Rmarkdown/pandoc document

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

Is there any possibility to separate long frontmatter in Rmarkdown to separate files. For example:

Let's say I have a `index.Rmd` file with following metadata,

```
---
title: 'My awesome title'
author: Me
date: `r Sys.date()`
---
```

I have a separate YAML file called `details.yml` with following contents which needs to be a part of this `index.Rmd` file when rendering.

```
---
bibliography: references.bib
biblio-title: 'References'
---
```

Comment: I have also asked the question https://community.rstudio.com/t/separate-frontmatter-metadata-in-rmarkdown-doucment/27606?u=therimalaya, but could not find the answer quicker. I hope that is not a problem.

Comment: [Here's an issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/297) from a while back that might have some workarounds